# How to detect string regardless uppercase, lowercase, with/without space in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I am dealing with csv file that the column names are changeable.

For example, the column names always have like "First Name", "Last Name", "Phone Number", etc. However, every time I download this csv file (update everyday), column names could change to "FirstName" or "first name" or "firstname" or even "firstNAME". Since I have to match the column to my own database columns, I could not use index.

The solution I could think of for now is to change all columns every time the script read the csv file.

```
csv_table = pd.read_csv(filename)
custom_col_name = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Phone Number']
csv_table.columns = custom_col_name
```

But if someday they (who generates the csv file) decide to change the order of columns, my script and result would be mess up.

Is there any way that I could set a pattern to look for and then change it.

Something like this:

1. read csv
2. look for column similar to 'first name'
3. change that column to 'First Name'
4. (repeat for all columns)

Comment: Would it be enough to convert the column names you receive to lower case and then to see which ones contain `'first'`, `'last'` or `'phone'`?

Comment: Building on quamrana's comment, you can lower-case a string by calling it's `.lower()` method: `your_string = "First Name".lower()`, and you can write an `if` statement to check it: `if "first" in your_string and "name" in your_string: do_something`

Answer (score 2):

Rename the columns by converting the column names to lowercase and removing whitespace.

```
import re
df.columns= df.columns.str.lower()
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub('\s+', '', x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Define the desired column names (order doesn't matter)
target_names = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Phone Number']

# Build mapping dictionary
mapper = {}
for col_name in df.columns:
    for target_name in target_names:
        for_compare_1 = col_name.lower().replace(' ', '')
        for_compare_2 = target_name.lower().replace(' ', '')
        if for_compare_1 == for_compare_2:
            mapper[col_name] = target_name
            break

# Rename the columns
df = df.rename(columns=mapper)
```